# ionic concatenation problem in the img tag

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, concatenation

I am having a problem concatenating the address of the array that contains image addresses. When I write the simple address without concatenation it works fine.
Thank you for helping me.

the simple address that allows access to the table is as follows and works.

`<img class="info" [src]="tmdbBanners.theme1[0]" />`

"theme1" must change according to what the user chooses

"theme1" is under the variable "form.banners"
so I tried several concatenation but it does not work. for example :

`<img class="info" [src]="tmdbBanners + form.bannieres + [0]" />`

ou

`<img class="info" [src]="tmdbBanners + "." + form.bannieres + [0]" />`

when I compile my application, the url of the image looks like this:

`<img class="info" src="[object Object]theme10">`

the result should display the image and give a valid url in the img tag

Answer (score 0):

In HTML file do the following changes:

```
<img [src]="getUrl(variable1,variable2)" />
```

In ts file do the following changes:

```
getUrl(variable1,variable2){
    return variable1+variable2;
}
```

Note: pass variable to method `getUrl(variable1,variable2)` in a such a way so that complete image URL will get return

Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work, I did this below:
`test(formBanners, banners){
    let test = this.banners + this.formBanners + [0];
    return console.log(test);
  }`

return in console '[object Object]theme10'

Comment: Welcome! and sorry I didn't provide you exact solution but yes this will guide you to solve issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct syntax, here it is:

```
<img class="dl" [src]="tmdbBanners[formBanners][0]" />
<img class="dl" [src]="tmdbBanners[formBanners][1]" />
<img class="dl" [src]="tmdbBanners[formBanners][2]" />
<img class="dl" [src]="tmdbBanners[formBanners][3]" />
```

returns the registered address in the table and displays the image correctly.
Thank you for the help you provided.